# PHP Search change the url of action

Tags: php, html, forms

I am trying to create a search page where viewers can search through. Anyhow I have it all sorted but my search page is at "myurl.com/?p=search" although in my form [below] I have tried to put ?p=search as the action although after submitting the form I am faced with my url being
"myurl.com/?keyname=hey" instead of how its meant to be of "myurl.com/?p=search&keyname=hey"

```
<form action="?p=search" method="get">
  <label>Name:
  <input type="text" name="keyname" />
  </label>
  <input type="submit" value="Search" />
</form>
```

Any idea how I can change it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add a `hidden` input field:

```
<input type="hidden" name="p" value="search" />
```

Or use the method POST so as to send your search query outside of the URL, leaving it untouched.

Comment: Its now coming up with "mysite.com/?keyname=hey&p=search", I need the ?p=search at the front of ?keyname. The opposite way around.

Comment: @user3124460 It doesn't matter in which order those are.

Comment: @user3124460 as they are `GET` values, the order doesn't matter. `p` is just a variable containing the `search` string and will be processed exactly the same way if it's at the beginning or the end of the URL.

Comment: @AlejandroIván My pages are not like home.php, index.php, search.php. What I mean is my whole sites pages are ?p=home ?p=index ?p=search which is helped by my .htaccess. ?p=search MUST be at the front for the page to work.

Comment: @AlejandroIván Plus I need my url to look like: ?p=search&t=[SEARCH VALUE HERE]   Notice how between the search and the t there is a &. I need that.

Comment: @user3124460 You are probably doing something wrong with your `.htaccess` then. I suggest you post a new question asking for help with that. Don't forget to include any and all relevant line from your `.htaccess`.

Comment: In any case, you can change the order in which the parameters appear in the URL by changing the order of the `<input>` in your code.